# Calculate average of time difference between consecutive row

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would be the most efficient query to calculate the average of time difference between consecutive rows in a table? **Note that the table has no primary key.**

If the table looks like below:

```
|     tran_end_time     |
|-----------------------|
|2022-02-08 07:04:46.610|
|2022-02-08 07:09:47.403|
|2022-02-08 07:14:48.100|
|2022-02-08 07:20:03.973|
```

Then I need the answer to be:

```
avg('2022-02-08 07:20:03.973' - '2022-02-08 07:14:48.100',
    '2022-02-08 07:14:48.100' - '2022-02-08 07:09:47.403',
    '2022-02-08 07:09:47.403' - '2022-02-08 07:04:46.610')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `DATEDIFF` along with `LAG`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tran_end_time,
           LAG(tran_end_time) OVER (ORDER BY tran_end_time) AS tran_end_time_lag
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, tran_end_time_lag, tran_end_time)) AS diff_avg
FROM cte
WHERE tran_end_time_lag IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause in the final query above ensures that we do not include any diff involving the earliest record.

Comment: Guess not: `Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.`

Comment: Correct, was parallely working on a similar query which also works: ```SELECT AVG(a.diff)
FROM (SELECT tran_end_time,
       DATEDIFF(minute, tran_end_time,
                LAG(tran_end_time) OVER (ORDER BY tran_end_time)) AS diff
    FROM your_table) a
WHERE a.diff IS NOT NULL```

Comment: Will do after the time limit :)